# Curried Functions in ML

Tags: ml

I need to write a polymorphic function in ML such that it's signature would be:

sig4 = fn : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a) * ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a

My current version is:

```
fun sig4 (f, g) a c b =
    if 1 > 2 then g(f(a) b c)
    else if 2 > 2 then f(a) b
    else g(a);
```

and it produces:

sig4 = fn : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a) * ('a -> 'c -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'c -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need any branching (`if ... then ... else ...`) to achieve this. Basically, given

```
fun sig4 (f, g) a c b = ...
```

the result of a call `sig4 (f, g) a c b` has to be of type `'c -> 'a`. If you would use

```
f a b
```

you got the type

```
('a -> 'b -> 'c) * 'd -> 'a -> 'b -> 'e -> 'c
```

To get `'a -> 'b` instead of `'d`, just apply `g` to `a` as the second argument of `f`, i.e.,

```
f a (g a)
```

then you get

```
('a -> 'b -> 'c) * ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'd -> 'e -> 'c
```

Now specialize `'c` by making sure that `f` takes 3 arguments

```
f a (g a) c
```

Resulting in

```
('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) * ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c -> 'e -> 'd
```

How to achieve that `'d` is turned into `'a`? Well, just use the result of `f a (g a) c` as argument to a function that takes an `'a` (you have 2 choices). E.g.,

```
f (f a (g a) c)
```

with type

```
('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a) * ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c -> 'd -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a
```

This is almost what you want. I'm sure you will figure out the rest.